# how to create multi pages with different headers using react routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to create 2 multi-pages UIs(managementUI and documentUI) with different headers.

updates:
the header contains navigation buttons to open and display different subpage components between the header and footer of the UI it belongs to.

e.g. the ApiCardGrid component will be displayed in managementUI.

However, the subpage cannot open in the outlet between header and footer when I clicked button in navigation header.

in App.tsx

```
function App() {
  const [totalApiData, setTotalApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api-documents").then((res) => {
      setTotalApiData(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/apiManagement"
              element={<ManagementUI />}
            >
              <Route
                path="apis"
                element={<ApiCardGrid spacing={2} size={3} />}
              />
            </Route>
            <Route
              path="/documents"
              element={<DocumentUI />}
            ></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

(update) Following comments made by @Drew Reese, in ManagementUI, I put an Outlet between header and footer to render the contents of subpages like ApiCardGrid. In ManagementUI.tsx:

```
function ManagementUI() {
  const [totalApiData, setTotalApiData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("/api-documents").then((res) => {
      setTotalApiData(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="management-ui">
        <div className="management-header">
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className="management-content">
          <Outlet />
        </div>
        <div className="management-footer">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

(update)API List button that link to /apis to display ApiCardGrid component in the Header:

```
<Header>
<Toolbar
          disableGutters
          variant="dense"
          id="header-primary-navigation"
          className="gds-primary-navigation"
        >
          <nav>
            <Button className="gds-button-primary-navigation" href="/apiManagement/apis">
              API List
            </Button>
            <Link to="/apiManagement/apis">API List</Link>
            <Button className="gds-button-primary-navigation" href="/apiInfo">
              API Info
            </Button>
            <Button className="gds-button-primary-navigation" href="/addApis">
              Add API
            </Button>
            <Button
              className="gds-button-primary-navigation active"
              href="/active"
            >
              active page
            </Button>
          </nav>
        </Toolbar>
</ Header>
```

similar in Header2
However, when I open UI1 localhost:3000/UI1, the UI1 opened successfully, but if I click button subpage1 to try to display subpage1 in UI1, the console responds error:"No routes matched location "/subpage1".(solved following answer of @Drew Reese)

update:
When I input url http://localhost:3000/apiManagement, the UI shows up. However, when I clicked the API List button, the url jumps to http://localhost:3000/apiManagement/apis, but the subpage item not shows up. I opened inspect tool, but no errors in console.

[image]

The subpage(ApiGridCard) supposed to display like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When rendering components on routes that render ***descendent*** routes the parent routes necessarily need to append the path wildcard `"*"` to their paths to allow descendent path matching.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/UI1/*"
      element={<UI1 />}
    />
    <Route
      path="/UI2/*"
      element={<UI2 />}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

An alternative is to create UI layout routes that render the appropriate header component and an `Outlet` for ***nested*** routes to render their element into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const UI1 = () => (
  <div >
    <div >
      <Header1 />
    </div>
    <div >
      <Outlet />
    </div>
    <div >
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </div>
);

const UI2 = () => (
  <div >
    <div >
      <Header2 />
    </div>
    <div >
      <Outlet />
    </div>
    <div >
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/UI1" element={<UI1 />}>
      <Route path="subpage1" element={<Subpage1 />} /> // "/UI1/subpage1"
      <Route path="subpage2" element={<Subpage2 />} /> // "/UI1/subpage2"
    </Route>
    <Route path="/UI2" element={<UI2 />}>
      <Route path="subpage3" element={<Subpage3 />} /> // "/UI2/subpage3"
      <Route path="subpage4" element={<Subpage4 />} /> // "/UI2/subpage4"
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit how-to-create-multi-pages-with-different-headers-using-react-routes]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited App.tsx following your example, as well as added <outlet/> in UI1 and UI2. However, when I click the subpage1 button in header, the url jumps to localhost:3000/UI1/subpage1, but the subpage1 not shows up in the body area, though the header and footer still exists.

Comment: @HenryBai I see. I'll see about standing up a running codesandbox demo.

Comment: @HenryBai Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-create-multi-pages-with-different-headers-using-react-routes-70k7iw?file=/src/App.js) demo of the routing with outlets and nested routes. I've also updated my answer to include a link to the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for creating an demo code! I followed your demo to updated my code as you can see in updated question. But when I clicked the API List button, only url changes to http://localhost:3000/apiManagement/apis but the subpage content(ApiGridCards) not displayed. Is there any thing I missed?

Comment: @HenryBai What exactly are these button components doing? With an `href` prop I am suspecting they are mutating the URL or reloading the app or anything else that is weird. Can you add the `Button` component code to your post here?

Comment: Updated, it's in the question. I even tried to use Link to replace the API List button like your demo. Still not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248212/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-henry-bai).